# Using one IPython for multiple environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, spyder

Is it possible to install IPython in base environment and use it in a different environment, maybe by installing `ipykernel` in there and somehow linking to base IPython? I am thinking something like Spyder, where you only need to install `spyder-kernels` in that environment and link its python executable to the python interpreter in base Spyder (heard similar things with Jupyter too). Otherwise I'll have to install IPython for every environment. I'm using Windows 10 and latest miniconda.

Comment: You can add a kernel for one env to jupyter on another env.  https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments

Comment: I use ipython, not jupyter, but was wondering if something like what works for jupyter could work for ipython too.

Comment: I think that's not possible because IPython is not designed to run with multiple Python interpreters.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can install ipython just to your base python env. Then when you create a virtualenv as a copy of that base python distribution, specify incremental dependencies on a per project basis using a `requirements.txt` file. You can read more about using virtualenv and pip to accomplish what you want on this brief article in the [hitchhiker's guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: They're using Conda, not pip and virtualenv.